# why QT progressbar maximum value is limited to 99%?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have started to learn QT programming, i was practicing basic signal and slot programming, i have written following code

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
         QMainWindow(parent),
              ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
      {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        ui->progressBar->setValue(1);
        ui->progressBar->setRange(0,100);
        connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                                    ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
      }

     MainWindow::~MainWindow()
          {
          delete ui;
          }
```

The problem is when i move horizontal slider to its maximum value the progress bar shows the value of 99% max. Not 100%. Is it default value in QT to display? or am I making some mistake in code? please help. Thanks

Comment: Likely because horizontalSlider has 0-99 range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in paulm's comment, the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#QAbstractSlider) state that QAbstractSlider defaults to a range of 0-99. You will never reach 100 using that slider.

You can confirm this by setting the range of your QProgressBar to match that of your slider by doing the following in your `MainWindow` constructor:
(edited for complete code)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* naive way */
    //ui->progressBar->setValue(1);
    //ui->progressBar->setRange(0,100);

    /* "correct" way - note that I set the range FIRST */
    ui->progressBar->setRange(ui->horizontalSlider->minimum(),
                              ui->horizontalSlider->maximum());
    ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->value());  //initialize the progress bar to slider's initial value

    connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
            ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
}
```

Comment: Really solved my problem. +1 is all i worth to do as thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should set your slider's properties corresponding to the progress bar.

I mean, use a well `setMinimum` and `setMaximum` in the slider which maximum value of slider sets progress bar to 100%